# Ionic server not running

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have just started learning mobile app development and chose Ionic framework. I have installed `npm(4.2.0), node(v7.10.0), ionic(3.1.2) and cordova(7.0.1)`. Since I am a beginner, I have started to learn ionic v1. I could not degrade my ionic version from v3 to v1 in Ubuntu. So I started my first app using the command `ionic start simple-login --type ionic1`. App created successfully. But could not run its server. Server throws an error. Please find the screenshot attached below.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: answer aside but if you are a beginner stop learning ionic v1..start the latest version i.e, ionic3.. both v1 and v3 are different you will get confused when you start v3..

Comment: I thought that basics should be learnt first. Isn't  that necessary?

Comment: that's what..v1 is mostly different and uses angular1 whereas ionic 2+ uses angular2 and typescript with many new features..so start with ionic latest basics. you can learn without any problems

Comment: okay @varunaaruru. Thank you.